# Run file inside a zipfile?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Is it possible to run a .html or .exe for example, that is inside a zipfile? I'm using the Zipfile module.

Here's my sample code:

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile("c:\\test\\test.zip", "r")
x = ""
g = ""
for filename in z.namelist():
    #print filename
    y = len(filename)
    x = str(filename)[y - 5:]
    if x == ".html":
        g = filename
f = z.open(g)
```

After `f = z.open(g)`, I don't know what to do next. I tried using the `.read()` but it only reads whats inside of the html, what I need is for it to run or execute.

Or is there any othere similar ways to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure behaviour you want, so it's hard to help you make it happen.  Take the zip file out of the equation. Imagine you have a plain ".html" file, e.g. `g = "testfile.html"`. What behaviour do you want to see from the computer?

Comment: what i would want is, for it to launch the testfile.html on a web browser. like after the g = "testfile.html" theres a code that will open it on a web browser. (but testfile.html is inside a zipfile)

Comment: I suggest you add to your question the code to open the file in a web browser, run the executable, etc., which you'd use if the file was out of the zip file. Do you already know how to do this part?

Comment: i got the code on running it outside of the zipfile, the challenge is how do i run it, if it is inside the zipfile, i wish to re create where if you open a zipfile and double clicks on the html file inside the zipfile. it will automatically opens on a web browser. this is under windows btw

Comment: You "got the code on running it outside of the zipfile". Good. What happens when you give the file handle `f` from `z.open(g)` to this code?  What doesn't work? What behaves differently?  It would help if you show us this code.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach will be to extract the required file to the Windows temp directory and execute it. I have modified your original code to create a temp file and execute it:

```
import zipfile
import shutil
import os

z = zipfile.ZipFile("c:\\test\\test.zip", "r")
x = ""
g = ""
basename = ""
for filename in z.namelist():
    print filename
    y = len(filename)
    x = str(filename)[y - 5:]
    if x == ".html":
        basename = os.path.basename(filename) #get the file name and extension from the return path
        g = filename
        print basename
        break #found what was needed, no need to run the loop again
f = z.open(g)

temp = os.path.join(os.environ['temp'], basename) #create temp file name
tempfile = open(temp, "wb")
shutil.copyfileobj(f, tempfile) #copy unzipped file to Windows 'temp' folder
tempfile.close()
f.close()
os.system(temp) #run the file
```

Comment: Don't use `os.system()` use `os.startfile()` on Windows; `subprocess`, `webbrowser` modules on other OSes.

Comment: `tempfile` is more robust than `os.environ['temp']`

Comment: you could use `os.path.splitext()` to extract file extension or just `filename.endswith('.html')` to check it e.g., see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8938550/4279).

Comment: hi thanks for the teaching let me study it again for a while. i need time for this to sink in my head =) thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Run the first `.html` file in a zip archive specified at the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile
import webbrowser
import zipfile
from subprocess import check_call
from threading  import Timer

with zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], 'r') as z:
    # find the first html file in the archive
    member = next(m for m in z.infolist() if m.filename.endswith('.html'))
    # create temporary directory to extract the file to
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    # remove tmpdir in 5 minutes
    t = Timer(300, shutil.rmtree, args=[tmpdir], kwargs=dict(ignore_errors=True))
    t.start()
    # extract the file
    z.extract(member, path=tmpdir)
    filename = os.path.join(tmpdir, member.filename)

# run the file
if filename.endswith('.exe'):
    check_call([filename]) # run as a program; wait it to complete
else: # open document using default browser
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename) #NOTE: returns immediately
```

#### Example

```
T:\> open-from-zip.py file.zip
```

As an alternative to `webbrowser` you could use `os.startfile(os.path.normpath(filename))` on Windows.

Comment: hi thanks for the teaching let me study it again for a while. i need time for this to sink in my head =) thanks guys